# Unable to view source code of a package in R

Tags: r, r-caret

I am trying to view the source code of the function knnreg in caret.

```
> getAnywhere(knnreg.default)
A single object matching ‘knnreg.default’ was found
It was found in the following places
  package:caret
  registered S3 method for knnreg from namespace caret
  namespace:caret
with value

function (x, ...) 
{
    if (!any(class(x) %in% "formula")) 
        stop("knnreg only implemented for formula objects")
}
<environment: namespace:caret>
```

What's happening? Where is the source code?

Comment: Have a look at [**this nice post**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19226816/how-can-i-view-the-source-code-for-a-function/19226817#19226817)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the error message is pretty obvious:

> knnreg only implemented for formula objects

Use `getAnywhere(knnreg.formula)` to see the source code.

Comment: very obvious indeed... Thanks!

Comment: This might help when you want to see all the methods for a class: `methods("knnreg")`